# Python load values from JSON file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Hello I’m trying to do a python script to process and print the multiple values for instance for customerPrice and totalAvailability. I tried to make the script as: variables as shown:

```
import requests
import json
import csv


with open('C:/asg/ftpfiles/API/test/resultsing.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)


property_values = [item['totalAvailability'] for item in data]
property_values2 = [item['customerPrice'] for item in data]



print (property_values)
print (property_values2)
```

The problem is not working.

the resultsing.json JSON file similar to this:

```
[
  {
    "part": "76678",
    "vendorPartNumber": "SDSQUNC-016G-AN6IA",
    "upc": "0619659134587",
    "vendorNumber": "408U",
    "vendorName": "SANDISK MOBILE",
    "description": "16GB SANDISK ULTRA MICROSDHC   FLSH CLASS 10 100MB/S UHS-I CARD",
    "productClass": "B",
    "uom": "EA",
    "acceptBackOrder": true,
    "productAuthorized": true,
    "returnableProduct": false,
    "endUserInfoRequired": false,
    "availability": {
      "available": true,
      "totalAvailability": 5053,
      "availabilityByWarehouse": [
        {
          "location": "Jonestown, PA",
          "warehouseId": "80",
          "quantityAvailable": 1553
        },
        {
          "location": "Mira Loma, CA",
          "warehouseId": "10",
          "quantityAvailable": 7,
          "quantityOnOrder": 1875,
          "quantityBackorderedEta": "2021-07-09"
        },
        {
          "location": "Carol Stream, IL",
          "warehouseId": "40",
          "quantityAvailable": 3493
        }
      ]
    },
    "pricing": {
      "currencyCode": "USD",
      "customerPrice": 9.13
    }
  },
  {
    "part": "1A8249",
    "vendorPartNumber": "JKLIUUH",
    "upc": "0619659134587",
    "vendorNumber": "408U",
    "vendorName": "SANDISK MOBILE",
    "description": "16GB SANDISK ULTRA MICROSDHC   FLSH CLASS 10 100MB/S UHS-I CARD",
    "productClass": "B",
    "uom": "EA",
    "acceptBackOrder": true,
    "productAuthorized": true,
    "returnableProduct": false,
    "endUserInfoRequired": false,
    "availability": {
      "available": true,
      "totalAvailability": 8900,
      "availabilityByWarehouse": [
        {
          "location": "Jonestown, PA",
          "warehouseId": "80",
          "quantityAvailable": 1553
        },
        {
          "location": "Mira Loma, CA",
          "warehouseId": "10",
          "quantityAvailable": 7,
          "quantityOnOrder": 1875,
          "quantityBackorderedEta": "2021-07-09"
        },
        {
          "location": "Carol Stream, IL",
          "warehouseId": "40",
          "quantityAvailable": 3493
        }
      ]
    },
    "pricing": {
      "currencyCode": "USD",
      "customerPrice": 9.13
    }
  }
]
```

How can the script be modded to process al the values of customerPrice and totalAvailability? In the JSON file I show only 2 but can be unlimited. Each different group of values are separate by coma and each one starts with ‘part’ value.

Comment: "The problem is not working." what's the problem **exactly**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one error in your code.

First you need to check `'availability' in item` and `'pricing' in item` for get `totalAvailability` and `customerPrice`.

For that your final code look likes:

```
import json

with open('C:/asg/ftpfiles/API/test/resultsing.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

property_values = []
property_values2 = []

for item in data:
    if 'availability' in item:
        property_values.append(item['availability']['totalAvailability'])
    if 'pricing' in item:
        property_values2.append(item['pricing']['customerPrice'])

print(property_values)
print(property_values2)
```

**Result :**

```
[5053, 8900]
[9.13, 9.13]
```

Comment: Oh thank you. I see what you mean about the error. It works perfect your fix. Thank you so much for the help.